# Javascript does not redirect to URL in an if-else case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried the following javascript page loaders for the sake of trying what's not working:

```
window.location.href = url
window.location = url
window.location.assign(url)
window.location.redirect(url)
```

Not one of them makes it to the correct page. And everytime I click on the button, it keeps on catching the first `if` case even though I clicked the second button. Am I doing something wrong with my if-else statements or the way I redirect it?

I also tried doing `onclick=`, paired with a `switch case`, `window.location.href` still doesn't come through.

My HTML:

```
<form id="action_option" onsubmit="redirect_to_url()" action="">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-space col-sm-3" value="View Object"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-space col-sm-3" value= "View Detail"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-space col-sm-4" value="View Inventory"/>
</form>
```

My Javascript:

```
 function redirect_to_url(){
    var action_option = document.getElementById("action_option");
    alert(action_option);

    var url = document.URL;
    url = url.slice(0, -1);


    if (action_option.elements[0].click) {
         url = url + "{% url 'objects_view' %}";
         alert(url);
         window.location.href(url);
    }
    else if(action_option.elements[1].click) {
        url = url + "{% url 'details_view' %}";
        alert(url);
        window.location.href(url);
    }
    else {
        url = url + "{% url 'inventory' %}";
        alert(url);
        window.location.href(url);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Edit:

Console Error -

> TypeError: window.location.href is not a function

- Removed Error by changing to `window.location.href = url` but still doesn't redirect.

Comment: check your browser console for error/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing `window.location.assign()` method with `window.location.href` property.

```js
window.location.href = url;  // directs the page to new location
window.location.assign(url); // navigates to a new page
```

See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

1. And your logic has flaws. You're checking if some element has a `click` member: `if (action_option.elements[0].click) { ... }`. This will always return `true`. So you'll never see the `else` sections execute.
2. Don't use multiple `submit` buttons. Make them regular buttons. Also you don't need a form, you're not submitting anything.

Do something like this:

```js
function redirectToURL(url) {
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="redirectToURL('URL 1')">button 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="redirectToURL('URL 2')">button 2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="redirectToURL('URL 3')">button 3</button>
```

Comment: yeah you're right. however I tried this now, but it only performs  `action_option.elements[0].click` even though I clicked the second button element. what do you think?

Comment: You're right! Thank you for explaining well. I was making it harder than it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Try `window.location.href = url;` instead.

If you don't need a form specifically, I would remove the form and do something like this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="redirect_to_url(1)" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-space col-sm-3" value="View Object"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="redirect_to_url(2)" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-space col-sm-3" value= "View Detail"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="redirect_to_url(3)" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-space col-sm-4" value="View Inventory"/>
```

And then in your Javascript:

```
function redirect_to_url(submitId){

    var url = document.URL;
    url = url.slice(0, -1);

    if (submitId === 1) {
         url = url + "{% url 'objects_view' %}";
         alert(url);
         window.location.href(url);
    }
    else if(submitId === 2) {
        url = url + "{% url 'details_view' %}";
        alert(url);
        window.location.href(url);
    }
    else {
        url = url + "{% url 'inventory' %}";
        alert(url);
        window.location.href(url);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this only removed my console error. mistyped this one thanks for pointing it out. But still doesn't redirect

Answer (score 1):

Check below code, I made some changes in your code and its working fine.

```js
 function redirect_to_url(x){
    /*var action_option = document.getElementById("action_option");*/
    //alert(action_option);

    var url = document.URL;
    url = url.slice(0, -1);


    if (x=="View Object") {
         url = url + "{% url 'objects_view' %}";
         alert(url);
   //console.log("objects_view");
         window.location.href=url;
    }
    else if(x=="View Detail") {
        url = url + "{% url 'details_view' %}";
        alert(url);
  //console.log("details_view");
        window.location.href=url;
    }
    else if(x=="View Inventory") {
        url = url + "{% url 'inventory' %}";
        alert(url);
  //console.log("inventory");
        window.location.href=url;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
   <form id="action_option"  action="">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-space col-sm-3" value="View Object" onclick="redirect_to_url(this.value)" />
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-space col-sm-3" value= "View Detail" onclick="redirect_to_url(this.value)"/>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-space col-sm-4" value="View Inventory" onclick="redirect_to_url(this.value)"/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
document.location = 'URL';

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing here.
 `window.location.href = url` is simulating a link clicked by the user.
`window.location = url` is transfering the user the desired url.
`window.location.redirect(url)` redirects the the user to the desired url with extra boolean param stating if the user should load the page from the server.